# extracting text from css node scrapy

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a catalog id number from this page:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

url = 'http://www.enciclovida.mx/busquedas/resultados?utf8=%E2%9C%93&busqueda=basica&id=&nombre=astomiopsis+exserta&button='

response = HtmlResponse(url=url)
```

using the css selector (which works in R with rvest::html_nodes)

```
".result-nombre-container > h5:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)"
```

I would like to retrieve the catalog id, which in this case should be:

```
6011038
```

I'm ok if it is done easier with the xpath

Comment: can you post complete code that you are using. May be I can help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have scrapy here, but tested this xpath and it will get you the href:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'result-nombre-container')]/h5[2]/a/@href
```

If you're having too much trouble with scrapy and css selector syntax, I would also suggest trying out **BeautifulSoup** python package. With BeautifulSoup you can do things like

```
link.get('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse `id` from `href`:

```
catalog_id = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'result-nombre-container')]/h5[2]/a/@href").re_first( r'(\d+)$' )
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be only one link in the h5 element. So in short:

```
response.css('h5 > a::attr(href)').re('(\d+)$')
```